# What does "threat" do in The Division?

Tags: the-division

I'm currently trying to figure out a good tank build for `challenging` dailys and came across the `threat` property that silencers and certain muzzle breaks have.

Threat is also mentioned in the character sheet.

### Examples of items with the threat property

- (almost?) all silencers reduce the threat by X%
- some muzzle breaks increase threat by X%
- loud vent muzzles always increase threat by X%

### Theories I have

#### Threat lets enemies flee

A higher threat level would drive the enemies away from you but then I wonder why I would want to reduce the threat as a sniper for example

#### Threat increases "aggro"

Another theory I have is that threat increases your aggro level and enemies will choose their target based on the highest threat. Then it would actually make sense to decrease your aggro level as a sniper / glass canon.

### Question

What does the threat property actually achieve?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's the aggro case.

Comment: increases an enemies chance to be suppressed

Comment: That's actually what I currently think it does

Comment: I find suppression is based on the number of rounds fired at an enemy in a certain time period.

Comment: In/decrease aggro will make most sense when teamed up. Didnt found a difference in solo play on this.

Comment: I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/43k1hk/what_is_reduced_threat/

Comment: All of the answers are wrong. It's not about aggro, it's about suppressing the enemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of playing all missions that are available as `challenging` I'm almost certain that threat is **a bonus that allows the user to suppress enemies more easily**.

This actually makes sense in these cases:

- Weapons with attachments with increased threat can be used to CC enemies very easily
- Weapons (especially snipers) with silencers (decreased threat) can be used to snipe enemies without them ducking down.

I will add a reliable source as soon as I find one.

Answer (score -7):

Is this seriously a question? This is a very basic and easy stay to understand.

Threat increase-gains enemy ai's attention to you

Threat reduction-lowers enemy ai's attention to you.

It's simple. Very very simple. Folks are over thinking this. It's common sense. If you tank, get increase threat mods.  If you dps and you get hit too much with a tank in group, get threat reduction mods. It's that simple guys.

Comment: If the entire basis were the sound of it, this would be it. Having gone into hordes with increased and decreased threat, I can say it isn't. It changes how easily you alert enemies to your presence and how they respond. They don't just mob you with a high value, they will strategically approach you. High threat is often greeted with more snipers and cover attempts.